# How to optimize my function to take less time?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm executing SQL query as

```
SELECT Id, COMMENT 
FROM student 
WHERE dbo.Remove (COMMENT) like '%N8AABENAABEPIVAA#GVCIZNV';
```

This is the `Remove` function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Remove] 
    (@StringData VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS VARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @word VARCHAR(200) = '';

    WITH Numbers AS 
    (
        SELECT TOP (LEN(@StringData )) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS N
        FROM master.dbo.spt_values
    )
    SELECT @word += SUBSTRING(@StringData, N, 1)
    FROM Numbers
    WHERE (N - 1) % 4 <> 0;

    RETURN @word;
```

I tried this function, it returns the result just fine, but when applying to 1'000'000 rows, it takes a lot of time - about 40 seconds.

How to optimize this function to take less time or any other way that do the same thing?

Comment: "How to optimize my function to take less time?" - Simple - don't use a scalar valued function

Comment: why do you need `spt_values`? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Add a RemoveComment field to your student table and calculate its value with an insert and update trigger. Then add a RemoveComment index. This way the work is spread out so evenly that it might not be noticed.

Comment: An index won't help unless you also `REVERSE` the stored value - due to the leading wildcard

Comment: True @MartinSmith, I can't see a use case where you would check for a string ending with a certain string. Though, exceptions exist for a reason.

Comment: i stored encrypted data in this Comment column and make a search in this encrypted data, so  wildcards  could be found in this encrypted values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make the following improvements.

- Use an inline Table Valued Function instead of a scalar function.
- Use `GENERATE_SERIES` instead of `spt_values` and `ROW_NUMBER`.
- Use `STRING_AGG` instead of variable coalesing to aggregate.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Remove] (@StringData VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN

SELECT
  word = STRING_AGG(SUBSTRING(@StringData, g.value, 1), '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY g.value)
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, LEN(@StringData)) g
WHERE (g.value - 1) % 4 <> 0;
```

To execute it, you don't use directly in an expression. You need to `APPLY` it.

```sql
SELECT
  Id,
  COMMENT
FROM student s
CROSS APPLY dbo.Remove(COMMENT) r
WHERE r.word like '%N8AABENAABEPIVAA#GVCIZNV';
```

GENERATE_SERIES is only supported on SQL2022 or Azure SQL, otherwise use a numbers generator,  see https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-1.

---

Having said all that, it seems you can just do something along the lines of using wildcards in the `LIKE`

```sql
WHERE s.COMMENT LIKE '%N8A_ABE_NAA_BEP_IVA_A#G_VCI_ZNV'
```

Comment: I guess that"s a good strategy for an ad-hoc query that isn't run very often. And I can't imagine there ever being so many students that this may run slowly. For large/very large tables, this may run way too slowly since it has to execute the function for each row before being able to apply the WHERE clause (AFAICT).

Comment: @Charlieface, Thank you for your valuable answer, but when creating your function on Table Valued, it gives an error to me as "The STRING_AGG function requires 2 argument(s)".

Comment: Sorry should be fixed now.

Comment: @TT. correct, but there isn't anything else to be done given the query requirements. I did suggest an alternative approach. An even better suggestion would be to use the info in this `LIKE` to set a `bit` column so you can find the data more easily (and index it).

Comment: @Charlieface , for the updated function, it gives me an error as "Incorrect syntax near 'g'."

Comment: I updated this by adding quma before g as CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Remove] (@StringData VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
SELECT
  word = STRING_AGG(SUBSTRING(@StringData, g.value, 1), '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY g.value)
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, LEN(@StringData), g)
WHERE (g.value - 1) % 4 <> 0;                                                                                                          but gives me error as Invalid object name 'GENERATE_SERIES'.

Comment: No adding that comma is not correct, it's just an artifact of the fact it can't find the function. `GENERATE_SERIES` is only supported on SQL2022 or Azure SQL, otherwise use a numbers generator see https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256910/discussion-between-samia-souror-and-charlieface).

Answer (score 0):

Since computing this is slow, it might make sense to compute it at write time or at cron jobs rather than each time you read the value. So you might be well-off to create a remove table into which you upsert a record when such a remove `COMMENT` is being defined and stored (or in cron jobs if you are okay with having this not 100% realtime in order to gain performance) and index this new table by the comment.

If the `%N8AABENAABEPIVAA#GVCIZNV` value is meaningful, for example it means the person who removed the record, then you can have a field for this in the new table to search by the `=` equals operator rather than a startswith which tends to be slower, you may even index this. We do not know what `%N8AABENAABEPIVAA#GVCIZNV` is, but it's a search term so this seems to be the value of two encoded fields. If so, then treat them as fields rather than substrings.